# regex to match RTRIM(LTRIM(xx)) = xx

Tags: regex

I am trying to jot down regex to find where I am using ltrim rtrim in where clause in stored procedures.

the regex should match stuff like:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(PGM_TYPE_CD))= 'P'))

RTRIM(LTRIM(PGM_TYPE_CD))='P'))

RTRIM(LTRIM(PGM_TYPE_CD)) = 'P'))

RTRIM(LTRIM(PGM_TYPE_CD))= P

RTRIM(LTRIM(PGM_TYPE_CD))= somethingelse))
```

etc...

I am trying something like...

```
.TRIM.*\)\s+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what you want:

```
[LR]TRIM\([RL]TRIM\([^)]+\)\)\s*=\s*[^)]+\)*
```

?

What's that doing is saying:

```
[LR]    # Match single char, either "L" or "R"
TRIM    # Match text "TRIM"
\(      # Match an open parenthesis
[RL]    # Match single char, either "R" or "L" (same as [LR], but easier to see intent)
TRIM    # Match text "TRIM"
\(      # Match an open parenthesis   
[^)]+   # Match one or more of anything that isn't closing parenthesis
\)\)    # Match two closing parentheses
\s*     # Zero or more whitespace characters
=       # Match "="
\s*     # Again, optional whitespace (not req unless next bit is captured)
[^)]+   # Match one or more of anything that isn't closing parenthesis
\)*     # Match zero or more closing parentheses.
```

If this is automated and you want to know which variables are in it, you can wrap parentheses around the relevant parts:

```
[LR]TRIM\([RL]TRIM\(([^)]+)\)\)\s*=\s*([^)]+)\)*
```

Which will give you the first and second variables in groups 1 and 2 (either \1 and \2 or $1 and $2 depending on regex used).

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for. I really want to make this automated and find the table name as well!! but I think that will be a long shot as I go through the files i'll have to read backwards and stuff. So I am going to run a query on oracle after I have the column name and find out what the table name is. thanks for help

Comment: Yeah, depends if there's an easy way to reliably identify all query blocks, then exclude ones that don't match the above - I'm not familiar with Oracle SP syntax, but I'd guess its getting more into SQL parser territory for that sort of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`[RL]TRIM\s*\(` Will look for `R` or `L` followed by `TRIM`, any number of whitespace, and then a `(`

Comment: this is also select stuff like `select RTRIM(LRTRIM(....`  I only want stuff there I am using rtrim ltrim in `WHERE` clause

Comment: I modified yours to be `[RL]TRIM\s*\(.*\s*=` I thin kthis will suffice

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
.*[RL]TRIM\s*\(\s*[RL]TRIM\s*\([^\)]*)\)\s*\)\s*=\s*(.*)
```

This will capture the inside of the trim and the right side of the = in groups 1 and 2, and should handle all whitespace in all relevant areas.